# Which processor family should I choose when compiling the kernel for an AMD Turion 64 X2 TL-52 CPU?

Tags: cpu, kernel

I have laptop with AMD Turion 64 X2 TL-52 CPU. Which processor family should I choose when configuring kernel?

Comment: Might help to state what options you have, or at least what distro we're talking about here

Comment: And which OS. NetBSD? FreeBSD, OpenBSD? Some Linux kernel?

Answer (score 1):

The [correct processor family](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K8/AMD-Turion%2064%20X2%20Mobile%20technology%20TL-52%20-%20TMDTL52HAX5CT%20%28TMDTL52CTWOF%29.html) is K8.

Comment: If you're new to compiling for native architecture make sure you set proper environment variables as well.